# Regular Expression not working in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have to compare two sentences. For minimal sentence length it is working as expected. But if I go for larger sentences, it is stuck there. For example:

```
let regex = /^.{0,30}.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*.{0,30}\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}\s*MY\s*SKY$/i
let Original = "BingeCR1234512345BingeCRBingeCR1234512345BingeCR1234512345BingeCR12345BingeCR1234512345BingeCR12345BingeCR1234512345BingeCR1234512345BingeCR12345BingeCR1234512345BingeCRBingeCRBingeCR12345MYSKY"

if (regex.test(Original)) {
   console.log("Valid ");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid ");
}
```

It doesn't even execute. Even it is not failing and not giving exceptions also. So I'm confused, Will the regular expression work only for sentences with fewer words and few substitutions .{0,30}. It's hanging because of the sentence length and dynamic portion.

Its working in Javascript, But in Node JS its hanging ( https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php ) & I'm facing the above issue. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iQfLoSd — I can't reproduce the problem. It successfully logs.

Comment: @Quentin https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php   Could you please try here?

Comment: Doesn't work there, it might be a fault with the wrapper they use or because the version of Node.js is extremely old and unsupported.

Comment: it indeed doesn't work in that tutorialspoint site but I don't think it's accurate to generalise to all of Node.js from that one resource. It most likely has a limit on execution time or resource allocation or something.

Comment: @Quentin If you try in the latest compiler or version also, Im facing the issue. Please help

Comment: @Quentin it works if the regex is very simple (tried with `/^.$/`) but not with the ginormous one in the question. My money is on TutorialsPoint killing the execution for being too long.

Comment: Depending on the regex engine this regex can produce *massive* ammounts of backtracking. To a degree that looks like the program crashing (i.e. not doing anything). Locally in Chrome it executes quickly, but that might not be true for all regex implementations.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm facing the issue in my application also, where we have higher execution time and resource than this. Please help.

Comment: @JoachimSauer In that case, what would be the better option for this kind of regex in NodeJs?

Comment: Haven't you already posted the exact same question a couple of days ago? Please avoid re-post questions you already asked. If you cannot retrieve the old question because it was deleted, it would be more sensible to try understanding why it was deleted rather than repeating it exactly as it was.

Comment: Also, I distinctively remember another user asking you for more details about what you wanted to "capture" with the RegExp, because s/he thought it could be greatly simplified.

Comment: @secan I have explained clearly in the comments for that particular user but i didnt get any further comments from anyone, and also I have understood after posting only that in javascript the scenario was working. So I have deleted the old question which was not getting enough attention & modified and posted it. Im new to this & trying to learn.

Comment: Then the "correct" approach would have been editing the old question not deleting it and posting an almost identical new one. Not getting enough attention is not a reason to re-post your question.

Comment: @secan the new question doesn't even include the explanation that apparently was in the comments of the old one...

Comment: @VLAZ that's my point; someone (not me) took some time and effort to try helping the OP but, by deleting the previous question, that information went lost while it could have been a stepping stone towards finding the correct answer.

Comment: @secan I'm in no way claiming that's incorrect. I wasn't aware of the old question. However, given that there was some relevant information in it, I'd have expected *at least* that to also be reposted. But the question lacks clarity in multiple directions.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, it was perfectly clear what you meant; apologies if I gave the impression your comments might have been misunderstood ;)

Comment: @secan Im learning & will correct my mistake going forward. But if you guys knw any way to solve this, please let me knw

Comment: To begin with (and without knowing what you are actually trying to match), it seems to me that your RegExp can be shortened to `/^.{0,60}(\s*BingeCR\s*.{0,30}){23}\s*MY\s*SKY$/i`.